# Find and remove href tags embedded in other href tags in php

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a project where text comes back with anchor tags embedded in other anchor tags and I'm trying to figure out a way to remove them efficiently.

Example:

`This is some text that <a href='link'>has a link about <a href='cars'>cars</a> and <a href='trucks'>trucks</a></a>`

What that should end up looking like is this:

`This is some text that <a href='link'>has a link about cars and trucks</a>`

I've considered the following:

1 - Going through and finding the a tag and then pulling out the information until the next a tag, check inside, and strip manually. But the content I'm getting back can be pages and pages of text, so I'm worried that will be really slow.

2 - Using regex to find tags within tags, but I'm honestly not that great at regex and everything I've tried using a php regex tester has come up empty.

I think option 2 would be the fastest and most elegant way, but I'm at a loss for how to accomplish it.

Does anyone have any suggestions for handling this type of problem in PHP?

Comment: are you storing it or just redisplaying it ? are the links you want to get rid of internal links or external ?

Comment: You could try regex->  "**/<a/g**"  to find your anchor tags

Comment: using regexes on html is bad enough. using regexes on malformed html? That's just insanity... Use html purifier or something, which are designed to handle trashy html.

Comment: The data comes in from an API that is called via PHP. It's one of many sources that are then compiled into a JSON response that our call gets and processes. So the content block is comes in pre-populated with href's that have embedded hrefs.